# Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer. No matching constructor was found

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7.1

We are migrating the project from sitecore 6.2 to sitecore 7.1.

I am trying to install the Active Directory Package "Sitecore Active Directory 1.1 rev. 130705" after upgrade of Lucene Search. 
I am getting the error

```
"Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer. No matching constructor was found.".
```

This is when I try to install the package using Installation wizard in sitecore 7.1

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As the `Exception Message` states its an issue with Sitecore's `ContentSearch`. It's not relating to version of Lucene or upgrade issues. The source of the issue is an incorrect Lucene or Solr (depending on which on you are using) `IndexConfiguration.config` file.

**Check this first**

Before proceeding make sure its not human error. This error will be displayed if you have the index file in the `App_Config/Includes/` more than once. Or if two or more Index Configuration files with the same xml element name.

**Option 1 - Remove the file**

You can either remove the offending IndexConfiguration.config from the `/App_Config/Includes/` folder and update the relating `Index` config files to use the `DefaultIndexConfiguration` in the `configuration` XML node;

```xml
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
```

**Option 2 - Fix the file**

The other option is to amend the custom IndexConfiguration. Most developers are familiar with creating a custom `Index` by copying the entire content of the config file so will copy the entire `DefaultIndexconfiguration` config to create a custom `IndexConfiguration` causing the Exception. This is not needed.

You only need a small number of the settings from the `DefaultIndexconfiguration` config as shown in this blog on how to [create a custom IndexConfiguration](http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/09/01/sitecore-content-search-creating-a-custom-defaultindexconfiguration/).

Answer (score 0):

I havn't checked out any code, but it sounds like the caller ("Sitecore Active Directory 1.1 rev. 130705") is compiled with an older version of Lucene.Net. Check the references of the AD-package and make sure you're using same version of Lucene.Net, or upgrade your AD-package to use the newer version.

I can't say how much coding is involved when upgrading the Lucene.Net related code (if you have access to it), but updates during the last year or two are mostly casing changes or get-methods transformed into real properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it had to do with a developer creating a backup file in the app_config\include directory.

They were updating one of the config files and in order to create a backup they just copied the file, which created another .config file (SameName-copy.config)

To fix we just renamed it to SameName-copy.config.bak-ccyymmdd

Hope this helps someone in the future with similar issue.

Answer (score -2):

Note that you cannot upgrade directly from 6.2 to 7.1. You will have to go in steps, going to 6.5, 7 and then 7.1

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question. This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.